# Why do I have these delays in my simulation of VHDL code?

Tags: vhdl

[image]

I tried to test two 2-digit BCD adders. One with CLA adders and the other with ripple.  I  have glitches in the simulation.

Are they from the clock or from my design?

```
library ieee ;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all ;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity testbench is 
end ;

-- here we check each possibility by generating 2 numbers from 0 to 99 then add these numbers using ripple bcd and cla bcd 
-- then we compare it to correct sum by using correctsum architecture 

architecture outputanalyser of testbench is 

-- intializing signals and give clock intial value 

signal clk : std_logic :='0';
signal a,b : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

signal mysumripple : std_logic_vector(8 downto 0 );
signal mysumcla : std_logic_vector(8 downto 0 );

signal behavioralsum : std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);


begin 
    clk <= not clk after 99 ns ; 
    -- the ripple adder work perfectly when clk is 99ns ,,,but cla needs only 61 ns 
    --i found these values by trying different values 

-- design verfication parts ,, ripple bcd ,,, cla bcd ,,, and the correctsum that gives us the behavioral sum 

s1 : entity work.designverficationparts(ripple)
    port map (a,b,mysumripple);
s2 : entity work.designverficationparts(cla)
    port map (a,b,mysumcla);
s3 : entity work.designverficationparts(correctsum)
    port map(a,b,behavioralsum) ; 

    process       


    type stringFile is file of string;  --  this type of files stores sequence of ascii characters 
    FILE outputFile : stringFile ;     -- we declaring file  handle 
    VARIABLE file_status : FILE_OPEN_STATUS; -- declaring file status variable 

    begin 

        FILE_OPEN(file_status, outputFile, "Result.TXT", write_mode);  -- we choose write mode so if there is error it can be written in file

     for x2 in 0 to 9 loop -- for second digit of first number  
        for x1 in 0 to 9 loop  -- for first digit of first number
           for y2 in 0 to 9 loop -- for second digit of second number 
             for y1 in 0 to 9 loop -- for first digit of second number 

             a(3 downto 0 )<= conv_std_logic_vector(x1, 4);
             a(7 downto 4)<= conv_std_logic_vector(x2, 4); 


             b(3 downto 0 )<= conv_std_logic_vector(y1, 4);
             b(7 downto 4)<= conv_std_logic_vector(y2, 4); 


             -- error messages 
     assert mysumripple = behavioralsum 
     report "Here the answer of ripples  is wrong "
     severity error ;

     if (mysumripple /= behavioralsum ) then
     write(outputFile, " the answer of ripples  is wrong ") ;
     end if ;   

     assert mysumcla = behavioralsum 
     report "Here the answer of carry look ahead  is wrong " 
     severity error ;


     if (mysumripple /= behavioralsum )  then 
     write(outputFile, " the answer of ripples  is wrong ") ;

     end if ;

     wait until rising_edge(clk) ;

     end loop    ;
     end loop   ;
     end loop    ;
     end loop   ;
     wait   ;   -- this wait to kill procces statement   
     end process ;
end;
```

Comment: is this behavioural or gate level (post synthesis or post PAR) simulation?

Comment: its gate level , I go from gates to full adder->4bit binary adder -> 1 digit bcd ->2digit...and the difference between carry look ahead and ripple is the 4 bit adder

Comment: That's a glitch, but that's a safe glitch between clock edges and it's inherent in any combinational path between flip flops in a sequential circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Gate level simulations model actual device delays.